# Can you add an index to List() to speed up search

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, indexing

Lets said you have something like this:

```
List<Car> Cars= new List<Car>
{
  new Car{ Color="Blue", Price=28000},
  new Car{ Color="Red", Price=54000},
  new Car{ Color="Pink", Price=9999},
  // ..
};
```

And want do some search like

```
Cars.Where( x => x.Color == "Blue")
Cars.Where( x => x.Price > 10000)
```

Do those search have to perform a full scan of the list or internally create an index like database so those search can be performed faster?

Or is there another structure more efficient to do this kind of search.

In my case the list is around 300k items but I do millions of search so need to optimize as much as I can.

Comment: have you considered  using dictionaries?

Comment: @StianStandahl dictionary has index to use on the filter examples I include?